# Sonata Admin Bundle filter show entity from role user

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to develop a dashboard with the SonataAdminBundle, which displays some entities depending on the role of the user.

For instance, if the connected user has the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`, all entities should be shown. But if the user is `ROLE_USER`, only a determinated entity should be shown, *not* all of them.

Is it possible do it in the service declaration of the entity?

Comment: you use `SonataUserBundle`?

Comment: It is used in my project, but I didn't configure it because it was installed yet, but I don't know how it works...

Comment: after you configure `SontaUserBundle` you can assign permissions to any action on Sonata panel.

Answer (score 0):

for future reference the trick is to use createQuery and permanentParamters in Sonata to be able to enforce filters. I have just written an article about that:
http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2016/09/sonata-for-symfony-hide-your-filters/

Comment: Please add here more details about your article and not only a link, that may become invalid some day.