# How to filter the instances of an entity that a user can see in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle, sonata

I have an entity "Vehicles" which has ManyToOne connection with another entity - "Department". I could set "department" property to a user. I would like this user (who has ROLE_DEPARTMENT_MANAGER role),  to be able to see (list, create, delete, etc.) only the vehicles from his own department.

When using Roles I could restrict access to specific actions. I think I should use ACL, but I am not sure how to do it and how Sonata Admin will behave.

I found similar question here, but nobody had answer it: [Sonata Admin Bundle filter show entity from role user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878789/sonata-admin-bundle-filter-show-entity-from-role-user)

Would you tell me how to do it in Sonata Admin Bundle.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the query used to generate the list in your VehicleAdmin class:

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#customizing-the-query-used-to-generate-the-list